# Run a tampermonkey user script with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, userscripts

Is it possible to run a Tampermokey script in headless chromium with Puppeteer?

If so, how do you do it?

Comment: Are you asking how to install and use an extension in headless Chromium or just asking how to [evaluate JS in the context of a page](https://pptr.dev/guides/evaluate-javascript)?

Comment: I think either will work? 

I have a tampermonkey userscript I would like to use in headless chrome and have been doing some research and trying to get it to run without any luck. I didn't realize an extension could be installed and ran in headless. What would you recommend?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. What does the Tampermonkey script do and why do you need to run it in the extension, specifically? Puppeteer basically _is_ Tampermonkey, in that it can automatically run arbitrary code in the browser, so the easiest approach may be to paste the Tampermonkey script into a `page.evaluate()`, depending on your use case and assuming the script doesn't make any special calls to APIs not in the browser (I know Greasemonkey has some such calls, `GM_` prefixed or whatever).

Comment: I believe the tampermonkey script does not make any calls to APIs. This would be evident with @require is that correct?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76918798/run-a-tampermonkey-user-script-with-puppeteer#comment135601055_76918798) "_What would you recommend?_": @3jay1 I recommend that you spend some time reading the published documentation for the tools that you want to use — they are well-documented and their documentation will answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this doesn't answer my question directly, the solution that ended up working for me was to write a custom chrome extension using the user script that I wanted to use. I then loaded the extension in headless: "new"  using this method:

https://pptr.dev/guides/chrome-extensions